# How to display phone gallery images to my grid view

Tags: gridview, memory-leaks, flutter

In fact this is a theoretical question in some way because I did achieve this, but have a memory blackout due to loading all images that exist in my phone. The following is how I store the images into a list.

```
final Directory extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

extDir.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false)
  .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
    print(entity.path);

    /* check for image and save */
    if(entity.path.endsWith("jpg")
    || entity.path.endsWith("png")
    || entity.path.endsWith("gif")
    ) {
      _PhoneImages.add(entity.path);
    }...
```

So, I pull out the paths in the list and show in my grid view as following..

```
new GridView.count(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: new ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              crossAxisCount: 2,

              children: new List<Widget>.generate(_PhoneImages.length, (index) {
                return new GridTile(
                  child: new GestureDetector(
                      child: new Stack(
                        children: [

                          new Card(
                            color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                            child: new Center(


                              child: new Image.file(
                                new File(_PhoneImages[index]),
                              ),
                            ),...
```

This does show the first few images, but slowly crashes and it gives me the following in the 'run' console

```
Lost connection to device
```

I have to restart. But of course it does same thing when trying to load. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that are causing issues here.

1. You're using shrinkwrap, with what sounds like a large amount of objects.
2. You're using Gridview.count rather than a builder
3. Your images don't have a predefined height

I'll explain why each of these is a bad idea:

**1) Using shrinkwrap:**

Shrinkwrap is, as it says in the docs:

> Whether the extent of the scroll view in the scrollDirection should be
>   determined by the contents being viewed.

A simple example to explain this is if your grid is supposed to take up the whole screen, but only has 2 items in it. If you have ShrinkWrap enabled, the grid will only take up the same amount of space as the two items; if shrinkwrap is off it will take up the entire screen but the items will still be at the top.

The difference is that with ShrinkWrap enabled, the GridView has to calculate the height of its' children every time it scrolls to make sure that the maximum height hasn't changed.

Most of the time, you don't want to be using ShrinkWrap unless you have a specific use case (i.e. a grid with a delete button underneath that you want to move up each time an item is deleted). You definitely don't want to be using ShrinkWrap with a large amount of items, as that means that the grid needs to layout each of those items before it can figure out the maximum extent of the list.

**2) Using GridView.count:**

By using one of the `count` type constructors, the grid view will immediately build (at least part) each and every item in the list. [As it says in the docs:](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

> To create a grid with a large (or infinite) number of children, use
>   the GridView.builder constructor with either a
>   SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount or a
>   SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent for the gridDelegate.

By doing this, it allows the gridview to instantiate only those items on the screen (and a bit cached on each side if you set cacheExtent).

**3) No predefined height:**

This is a common mistake. Because each item in the grid doesn't have a specific size, they delegate to their children to find a size. However, because Images don't have a size until they are loaded, this can cause problems.

Basically, each image is starting with a height of close to zero. That means that many, many images can fit on the screen so the phone tries to load all of the up. That's what is probably causing your memory issue and crash.

I recommend setting a size for the tiles of your grid or at least setting an aspect ratio so they can determine their height by that immediately. If you need to, you could have them delegate to the size of the image once it has loaded but it would probably be better to simply use a BoxFit for each of the images.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is great lesson. I did however use fixed height, and also boxfit to certain size. I think it could be shrink wrap or the size of the items itself which is causing memory overload. I found a way to resize with Image package and they look fine for now without crash but temporarily. The reason I use shrink wrap is because I am using grid-view inside a page view. This current grid is in the second page.

Comment: You still shouldn't need shrinkwrap in that case I don't think, unless you're doing something strange. The pageview scrolls horizontally while the grid scrolls vertically (by default at least), and shrinkwrap only affects the direction in which the grid scrolls. If both the grid and pageview are the same direction then that's a different case. Regardless, if you have shrinkwrap set, use count, or have the images without a height you're going to have problems - you need to fix all three.

Comment: If you added enough code to be able to run the example I could give it a try though.