# Fastest Way To Display 100 or more images in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

The purpose of this question is to find the best way to display a lot of images (20 or more) from the gallery. 
I need to display all the photos on the on the device. As you can see there could be a lot of images to be displayed, and when I try to display them all using different Image.file() widget, My phone (LG G2) gets slow and then the app completely crashes.

I think the Problem Is that I am Loading a lot of 4K Images (More Than 100) on a 5 years old Device. The Images actually displayed on the Screen at the same time are actually around 15, but I need to have something like a gallery, so all the images in a GridView.

So, I don't think it's the best option, maybe there is a function to downscale the image to like 100x100 px. But looking online I couldn't find anything. So, Is there a better way?

I get all the Image Paths and their folder using a Platform Channel to Android.

I get them all in a list like this:
[["Camera", "storage/emulated/0/downloads/1.png"], etc]

This is The UI I got: (Sorry For the Awful design)
[image]

There Are three Main components on the Screen, The IconButton With The Two Arrows:
The DropDownMenu and The GridView.

The IconButton requeries all the paths from android. in the List as stated above.
The DropDown Menu has a function on onChanged which creates all the Cards in the List used by gridView.

This is The Funciton:

```
void _onChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _currFolder = value;
      _photoCards = calculatePhotoCards();

    });
  }
```

And the calculatePhotoCards is this:

```
List<Widget> calculatePhotoCards() {
    List<Widget> list = new List();

    for (int v = 0; v < _foldersAndPaths.length; v++) {

      if (_foldersAndPaths[v][0] == _currFolder) {


        list.add(Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                child: Image.file(
                  File(_foldersAndPaths[v][1]),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,


              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
      }
    }

    print(list);
    return list;
  }
```

Where _foldersAndPaths is the List containing all the paths which their respective folders (as stated above), while _currFolder is the Selected Folder in DropDownMenu.

Comment: Please include the code you've used to try to load & display the images. Even with an older phone it shouldn't crash just loading up 20 images, so there's a good chance something else is going on.

Comment: And FYI - flutter does do some downsizing & caching of images by default, so you shouldn't have to worry about that too much.

Comment: On my LG G2, as I said i am loading more than 100, actually almost 500 hundred photos. I'm adding the code to the description

Comment: Right, but it shouldn't be loading all 100/500 at once but rather those currently on the screen. If you're trying to load all 500 into memory all at once, you're obviously going to have issues

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51994542/2927226) (ignore the question's code though - it isn't the greatest) for an explanation of what could be the problem...

Comment: Still with GridView.builder Images Take a lot to load or won't load at All

Comment: any updates on this guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to implement this to see if it was something to do with image sizing etc, as there have been a few questions about that in the past for remote images.

When I implemented it, I ran into the exact same problem as you. I thought that flutter did caching of images scaled to a reasonable size but that doesn't seem to be the case. It's actually loading up each image into memory, which is why you're getting a crash. It doesn't take that many images to run out of memory as by the time they're decoded into pixels they're pretty huge.

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21571) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2848) are bugs about this (I raised one myself) against flutter.

So unfortunately, I don't think there's a pure flutter way of doing this at the moment. There is a image package on pub that can scale down images but it does it directly in dart code so isn't all that performant.

Until those bugs have been fixed, you may have to look for an android-specific (and iOS-specific if you're interested in that) solution to this. That would entail using the android thumbnail creator to create a bitmap, then either saving that bitmap and passing it's URL back to flutter, or passing the bitmap's bytes directly.

Sorry I don't have a better answer than that!

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `cacheWidth` and `cacheHeight`

example:

```
Image.network(
  shop.shopPic,
  width: 46,
  height: 46,
  cacheWidth: 46,
  cacheHeight: 46,
)
```

Comment: Do you know how something similar can be achieved in DecorationImage?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using CachedNetworkImage and I had an issue with loading multiple Images and the app got to over 3GB ram because of it the solution was

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    height: height,
    width: width,
    memCacheHeight: height, //add this line
    memCacheWidth: width, //add this line
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
  ),
```

It reduced the memory usage from3GB to 60MB

Comment: This won't reduce the size of the image downloaded, but it will decrease the resolution at which the image will be displayed in the app, henceforth reducing the memory cost for images way bigger than the container they were displayed in.

Comment: @croxx5f Yes exactly I have a product list with high-quality images and the same image is used as a thumbnail and the main image of the product so that was the best solution for me to reduce the memory usage in the product list page.

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest solution, if you'd also want to tackle the bandwidth issue you would need to somehow implement image resize on the backend, or integrate a 3rd party service, in order to download images with just the required size. Other enhacement could be to use the CachedNetworkImage package, this way you will only pay the penalty of downloading the images once.